# Custom Profile Center Encrypt / Decrypt

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I built a standard custom profile/unsub center page and had support update the `%%profile_center_url%%` to my page `client.com/unsub?subid=%%subid%%&jobid=%%jobid%%`

After they confirmed the task was completed it would appear the url is encrypted but support's response has been quite slow so I'm hoping someone would be able to confirm this is an accurate assumption and advise what the standard encryption method used so I can update my landing page.

Sample URL:
`client.com/unsub?qs=10f2ef415503b732c94027f9abdd572e477e9b583f68d783960e13c7a69a82fe`

Adding the input from Support, after my request for more information:

*I took a look at your account and at the strings. We have an internal tool that allows me to decrypt the encoded string in the url. The URL example you provided me decrypts to:
e=james.clarke1014+test1@gmail.com&jid=1530999*

I tried the code provided by Adam and also tried queryParameter:

```
%%[

var @sk, @jid, @email, @subid, @monae, @monaj
SET @jid = AttributeValue("jid")
SET @email = AttributeValue("e")
SET @subid = QueryParameter("e")
]%%

@jid = %%=v(@jid)=%% <br>
@subid = %%=v(@subid)=%% <br>
@email = %%=v(@email)=%% <br>
```

Results were:
@jid = 
@subid = 
@email =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to provide an update, support made a mistake on the way the updated this profile center and actually encrypted it in a way you cannot use on a custom landing page.

*- "The problem is that the 'Secure_Link_Wrapping' Business Rule had a quality of '1'. This means any Profile Center or Unsubscribe Center would have the query parameters encrypted. 
The quality has since been updated to 'NULL'. The account should no longer encrypt the query parameters so the page will work again."*

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an encryption, it's link wrapping that is automatically applied to all links being sent out of Marketing Cloud.  The links should still work correctly when sent out.  If you would like to double check, I use http://www.wheregoes.com which shows the redirect path.

Answer (score 0):

@CCarswell is correct in that it is "link wrapping".  It's the encrypted subscriber context.

If you arrive at your page with a link like this, you can retrieve any of the subscriber's [**personalization strings**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) using the [**AttributeValue()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm) function in your page.  For example:

```
%%[

var @sk, @jid
set @sk = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
set @jid = AttributeValue("jobid") 

]%%
<br>@sk: %%=v(@sk)=%%
<br>@jid: %%=v(@jid )=%%
```

Comment: Adam, i noticed you're using default personalization strings, should I assume those are included in supports update to the tag? The ticket I submitted had custom ones based off what I had working before they updated the brand tag.

Comment: Hey @AdamSpriggs, I updated the question after i heard back from support and did another set of testing with your suggesting. I would seem either I'm missing something from you post or the function may not be effective in this situation